# Reactjs data changes, filename stays the same

Tags: reactjs, browser-cache

I have a picture, profile.jpg on my server. When I upload a new picture, replacing picture.jpg in data but not in name (in other words, the old profile.jpg gets replaced by the new profile.jpg, but the new one is also called profile.jpg). After my promise is returned, I call forceUpdate, but this doesn't do anything unless I change the actual url (src) of the image. See my code, in which I attempted to concatenate promises in order that react would recognize that the url is changing (from the correct url, to "empty", to the correct url again):

```
fetch('http://localhost:3000/change_pet_pic/?petID='+this.props.pet.id+'&userID='+this.props.pet.ownerID, { method: 'POST', body: form })
        .then(function(res) {
            return res.json();
        }).then(function(json) {
            var pet = $this.props.pet;
            pet.petPicture = "empty";
            $this.props.pet=pet;
            $this.forceUpdate();

            return json.picture_url;

        }).then(function(url){
            var pet = $this.props.pet;
            pet.petPicture = url;
            $this.props.pet=pet;

            $this.forceUpdate();
        })
```

Thanks for your tips!

Comment: It seems nothing wrong with your ReactJS code rather it should be a browser cache which returns the old image again and again as the filename looks same. What you can do is, you can access the image with different query string whenever the image is getting changed. So the first time, you can access this with `profile.jpg?v=1` and the second time, you can access it with `profile.jpg?v=2` like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems nothing wrong with your ReactJS code instead it should be a *browser cache* which is causing issue by returning the old image all the time as the image url looks same.

What you can do to get rid of this is, you can access the image with different *query string* whenever the image is getting changed.

So the first time, you can access this with `profile.jpg?v=1` and the second time, you can access it with `profile.jpg?v=2` something like that.

Comment: This looks like a great idea thanks for the quick response